# Why no "Open With..." when right-clicking on a .COM file in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, right-click

I'm trying to edit a file FRED.COM in Windows XP by right-clicking it and selecting "Open With...". But no such option appears. Does anyone know why, and what I can do about it?

I've looked at this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/30564/missing-open-with-when-shift-right-clicking-a-file-in-windows-7) but the circumstances are not quite the same.

Comment: In the future if you reference a specfic file, you need to describe what it is, otherwise there isn't any sense in using the exact filename.  It makes your question to specfic to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.com files are binary executeables. To be honest they are not intended to be editable. To make changes you would need to get the source code then re-compile the file. There are decompilers out there, but generally they don't provide particularly useful code.

Comment: Ah! That explains it. It so happens that this particular file is a VMS command procedure currently residing on my PC, and therefore text, but with a file extension .COM as is customary on VMS.

Comment: Well, it certainly makes sense to edit COM, EXE, and DLL files (or, for that matter, *any* file at all) using a hex editor.

Comment: While you can edit any file in a hex editor, that is still not the intention for binary executeables.