# How to open a PDF file in the Kindle app for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, kindle

On Amazon.com it says you can view PDF files from within the app but when I go through the menus I can't find a way to open a PDF file that's on my computer! How do I do it?

Comment: Could you provide a link to where on Amazon.com it says this? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_pc_ln_ar?docId=1000426311  Read under "New Features".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an command for this within the Kindle app itself. However, these two indirect approaches both allowed me to import/view PDF documents in the Kindle app:

- Copy or move the PDF file into your *My Kindle Content* folder, then relaunch the Kindle app. You can find the location of this folder through *Tools menu* / *Options* / *Content*.
- Open the PDF using the Kindle executable. You can either use the [Open With... option](https://superuser.com/questions/30564/missing-open-with-when-shift-right-clicking-a-file-in-windows-7) on the file itself and select the Kindle executable, or drag and drop the PDF's icon onto the executable's icon.